# Strange behavior with keyboard shortcuts on MS Access Form

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

This is an odd one. On a MS Access 2007 form, I am getting intermittent copy/paste keyboard shortcut problems. I will select text, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and my text is replaced with a letter "c". I then try to undo this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and I am rewarded with a letter "z". The same goes for pasting. If I have text on the clipboard and I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, I will normally get a "v" the first time, but usually if I keep trying, on the 2nd or 3rd try, the paste operation will work.

All keyboard shortcuts work as expected in other applications

Things I've tried

- Change keyboards: no effect
- Being very careful to ensure that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is properly held down before I hit the next key: no effect
- Clicking the menu buttons for copy/paste works as expected

Platform: Windows 8.1

**Update:**
I went through all the macros I have defined for the database and none of them have keyboard shortcuts defined as [described here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/run-an-access-macro-by-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-HA010239111.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two Possibillities:

First your Control Key is broken.

Second there are Macros assigned to these Shortcuts in the Access File (or even In Access it selfs) so Windows doesn't know which one it should do the System one (copy/paste undo ...) or the Macro.

To check First: Use the shortcut in an Application like Word where you knew it has functioned before.

For the Second: Have a look at the Menu Entry you should see the Shortcut next to it. Or go to the Create tab, in the Other group, click Macro and see if there are any Macros.

If this doesn't bring you to a solution, add some more details like Operating System and Access Version you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The keyboard shortcuts are working fine in all other programs I use (word, Firefox, notepad, etc). I'm not sure I know what you mean by "Menu Entry". Where should I look for that?

Comment: I mean the thing you use when you do it the Windows User way (by Mouse) have a look here http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC285549.jpg the thing which opens when you click on view is called a menu and the thing highlighted is called a menu entry. (as you can see on the entry "properties" shortcuts are normally shown at the right side of the menu entry. hope it's clear now.

Comment: Yes, it is (abundantly) clear now. Thanks. I don't remember tying any macros to keyboard shortcuts, but I'll double check anyway.

Comment: I checked the macros (see update on question), and that doesn't seem to be it. Any other ideas?

Comment: There are a few Posts on the Internet about Problems using Access 2007 under Windows 8/8.1 maybe this is one we should add to the List. I hope someone at Microsoft is able to help you more.